# How to import Vue in Single File Component when using TypeScript?

Tags: ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Single File Component and I need to import Vue:

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'
...
@Component({...})
export class Comp extends Vue {...}
```

I'm importing vue.js as module in the browser:

```
<script type="module" src="module/vue/vue.js"></script>
```

but I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

somewhere inside of an `eval()` which `vue-cli-service --target lib` generates. I'm loading the SFC as a module, too:

```
<script type="module" src="module/comp/comp.js"></script>
```

As a workaround, I tried to add the imports at the top of `comp.js`:

```
import Vue from '/module/vue/vue.js'
import Component from '/module/vue-class-component/vue-class-component.js'
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
...
```

but that doesn't help.

How can I rewire the imports to the paths that will be used on the web server? I checked the options of webpack but only found `resolve` which seems to help webpack find stuff while it packages. I need an "output rewrite" kind of option.

Note that I'm using ES modules, not CommonJS or RequireJS.
`tsconfig.json`:

```
compilerOptions: {"target": "ES2016", module: "ES2015" }
```

**Update** I tried to put the final path into the .vue file and use `configureWebpack.resolve.alias` in `vue.config.js` to allow the Vue compiler to locate the module but that also doesn't work.

`vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    runtimeCompiler: true,
    configureWebpack: {
        externals: [
            'module/vue/vue',
            'module/vue-class-component/vue-class-component',
        ],
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'module/vue/vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
                'module/vue-class-component/vue-class-component': 'vue-class-component/dist/vue-class-component.esm.js'
            }
        },
    }
}
```

`comp.vue`:

```
...
import Vue from './module/vue/vue'
import Component from 'module/vue-class-component/vue-class-component'
```

just gives

```
ERROR in .../src/comp.vue
16:17 Cannot find module 'module/vue/vue'.
```

Comment: Instead of "vue-class-component", can you give a try with vue property decorator. import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

Comment: @AmithaMahesh Thanks. That also doesn't work. The `vue-class-component` import isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem, I just kept it to show that Vue isn't the only import and the answer should work for other things as well.

Comment: It can't find the path because the external is setup incorrectly. It needs to point the global variable not the path.

Comment: My impression (I can be wrong) is when you use ES2015 modules, there is no global variable. Hence the error.

Answer (score 4):

## Overview

You can add `configureWebpack` in the `vue.config.js` to modify the Webpack configuration and in Webpack you can solve this issue using `externals`.

## Handling Externals

Externals provide a way for you to import external libraries.

In your webpack configuration you will add a line that looks something like this.

let's take `lodash` for example as the import and the global variable are different.

```
// webpack.config
externals: {
  'lodash': '_'
}
```

`_` is the global variable webpack can grab and `lodash` is the import it exposes.

At this point, you can do something like this.

```js
import * as lodash from 'lodash'
```

## Handling TypeChecking

To handle the type checking with this method you `npm install @types/...`  and TypeScript will pick up the types for that import.

## Modifying Webpack in vue.config.js

You can read about this [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#configurewebpack) but simply add the following to the vue.config.js file.

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    externals: {
      'lodash': '_'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does that map http://localhost/module/lodash/lodash.js to the import statement in the browser?

Comment: If you look at the compiled result you get this `module.exports = _;` for 'lodash' so it is expecting '_' to already exist. This simply exposes the global variable to webpack. In the case of Vue.js just like lodash it creates a global variable `Vue` which you can map in webpak. externals: { 'Vue' }. The Browser just runs Vue.js and creates the Vue global variable and webpack can reference it with whatever you specify. Using type="module" in your script or not the result is the same.

Comment: Long story short man this worked for me in my testbed. The only thing I might have done differently was I used a CDN for `Vue.js` `<script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Ah... I'm trying to use ES modules, not the old requirejs/commonjs stuff. So in the generated code, I see `import Vue from "vue"` which works for unit tests (npm/jest will find the stuff) but not in the browser (= ignored global symbols). And when I use the relative path which *should* work in the browser, tsc&jest break.

Comment: `tsconfig.json`: `compilerOptions: {"target": "ES2016", module: "ES2015" }`